# when i using formik and @shopify/polaris, my TextField; cannot be typed by users

Tags: reactjs, shopify, formik

In a react project, when using formik and @shopify/polaris, when I use a TextField; My TextField is not typeable. That is, the user cannot enter a value in it or change its value. Dear friends, I would be grateful if you could help me.

```
import { Form, FormLayout, TextField, Button, } from '@shopify/polaris';
import React from 'react';
import \* as Yup from 'yup';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';

export default function ContactUs() {

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            email: '',
            subject: '',
            message: ''
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            email: Yup.string().email("invalid email").required("required"),
            subject: Yup.string().required("required"),
            message: Yup.string().required("required"),
        }),
        onSubmit: (value, { resetForm }) => {
    
            console.log(value);
            resetForm();
    
        }
    
    })
    return <>
        <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <FormLayout>
    
                <TextField
                    readOnly="false"
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    autoComplete="email"
                    label="Email"
                    helpText={
                        <span>
                           { formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
                        </span>
                    }
                />
    
                <Button primary submit>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </FormLayout>
        </Form>
    </>

}
```